# Do we need UDID and BundleId when app file path has given in capabilities list?

Tags: android, automation, appium, appium-ios

Do we need UDID and BundleId when app file path has given in capabilities list when App file path given? Declared capabilities for the app as below:

```
//******************
File app_path = new File("/Users/Ram/Desktop/xyz.app.zip");

DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();

caps.setCapability("MobileCapabilitiyType.PLATFORM_VERSION", "8.1");
caps.setCapability("MobileCapabilitiyType.DEVICE_NAME", "iPhone 6");
caps.setCapability("MobileCapabilitiyType.BROWSER_NAME", "");
caps.setCapability("MobileCapabilitiyType.APP", app_path.getAbsoltePath());

IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub", caps), caps);

***********************************///
```

and the app is still launching in the emulator after running the script! In which scenario do we need to specify the UDID and BundleId?. If anybody clarifies this doubt would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**bundle id** is the essential desired capabilities for **Real ios Devices**.in case of emulator, **APP** would work.

udid comes in generic capabilities(ios &android) , however in android you can use **deviceName** instead of **udid**.

in ios **udid** is mandatory in case of Real ios devices, since you are using emulator, its not required.

By definition

udid:

> Unique device identifier of the connected physical device

bundleId:

> Bundle ID of the app under test. Useful for starting an app on a real
>   device or for using other caps which require the bundle ID during test
>   startup. To run a test on a real device using the bundle ID, you may
>   omit the 'app' capability, but you must provide 'udid'.

more information can be seen from here

http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

Hope that clears your doubt

Comment: Hi,  you said that "if bundle ID is present then omit the app capability", but it should vice-versa, because the app has the path of ipa file and its must capability. The Bundle ID is require if you use any removeApp() or InstallApp.  am i right ?

Comment: r u talking about physical device or simulator?

Comment: physical device